# Preserving a string's Xml encoded characters

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I need to update an XML document; using C# and preferably Linq To Xml. The source XML file has the following node:

```
<characters>Lorem &#xD;Ipsum</characters>
```

I need to update this node to something like this:

```
<characters>Lorem1 &#xD;Ipsum2</characters>
```

When I read in the string from the Xml; I get this:

```
"Lorem &#xD;Ipsum"
```

and when I write the string using

```
copyEl.SetElementValue(ns + "characters", "Lorem1 &#xD;Ipsum2");
```

the outputted Xml has the leading ampersand of the encoded character being re-escaped:

```
 <characters>Lorem1 &amp;#xD;Ipsum2</characters>
```

I want to preserve the Xml encoding in the original string as is; but am unsure as to how to do it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The beauty of using Linq-to-XML, or any xml abstraction class for that matter, is that you don't need to worry about string encoding.  Just pass in the string as a C# string, and let linq convert it to an XML string for you:

```
copyEl.SetElementValue(ns + "characters", "Lorem1 \rIpsum2");
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning of using proper XML APIs... Note that the question is about #xD that should be normalized (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-white-space) on read. So one need to carefully decide what should happen and what should be encoded (i.e. `\r` may be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

There is whitespace in your xml, which you can deal with in various ways using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.whitespacehandling.aspx